# Limits of functions continuous from the left

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $I$ be a bounded interval and let $f$ be a function defined on $I$.

Assume that $f$ is bounded above on $I$ and $f$ is increasing on $I$.

Let $t:= \sup \{ f(x)|x \in I \}$. If $I := (\alpha,\beta)$ where $\alpha < \beta$. Prove that 
$$\lim_{x \to b^-} f(x) = t.$$

I understand that if $f$ is increasing and bounded above then the sup will exist. But i don't understand how to prove that $\lim_{x \to b^-} f(x) = t.$ Could anyone help me out please? Thanks

Comment: Hint: Given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $y\in I$ such that $$t-\varepsilon<f(y)< t.$$

Comment: @DiegoMath ok, I understand this. t is the sup so this would make sense. I also notice that the set is open. So, how can I proceed from there? I am still a little confused. Thanks

Comment: Use the definition of lateral limit, given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $y\in I$ such that $t-\varepsilon<f(y)< t$, since $f(x)\geq f(y), \forall x>y$ just take $0<\delta<b-y$, hence $0<b-x<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-t|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: @DiegoMath Okay. Thank you! How would it be different if I = ($\alpha,\beta$] ? Would it mean that the sup is in the set?

Comment: In this case the only change will be $t-\varepsilon<f(y)\leq t.$ But the proof for the limit is analogous.

Comment: And everythiing else would be the same? We would still have f(x) ≥ f(y) and the remaining of the proof will be similar?

Comment: Yes, this is it!

Comment: Also, how does 0<b−x<δ imply that |f(x)−t|<ε ? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: If $0<b-x<\delta$ then $x>b-\delta>b-b+y=y$, then $x>y$, thus $t+\varepsilon>t>f(x)\geq f(y)>t-\varepsilon$, finally $|f(x)-t|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: You are welcome!